# PayPalのAPIエラーコード10412について教えてください。

Tags: paypal

PayPalの決済ページにリダイレクトされる際、下記エラーが出ました：
「この請求は支払い済みです。詳しい情報については、マーチャントにお問い合わせください。」
Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID
また、SetExpressCheckoutを呼び出した際、下記のエラーがでました：
L_ERRORCODE0=10412
Duplicate invoice

このエラーになる原因は何でしょうか、どう対応しますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このエラーが発生する原因は、マーチャントのウェブサイトからPayPalに渡した「請求書ID」のパラメータは以前の取引の「請求書ID」と重複しています。
「請求書ID」のパラメータは、
ウェブサイトペイメントスタンダードの場合、「invoice」パラメータです、
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/
エクスプレスチェックアウトの場合、SetExpressCheckout APIの「PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM」パラメータです、
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

アカウントのデフォルト設定では「請求書ID」が重複するとエラーになります。

「請求書ID」を重複しても問題ないマーチャントに対して、下記の手順でこの設定を変更することができます。

### www.paypal.comでログインして、個人設定->販売ツール->支払い受取りを拒否する　で更新をクリックし、下記の設定項目で「いいえ」を設定して保存してください。

支払いが間違って処理された場合、その支払いの受け取りを拒否する。
支払いの間違いを防ぐために、請求書IDが重複している支払いの受け取りを拒否します。
 はい。請求 ID 別に多重の支払を拒否する。

### いいえ。請求 ID 別に多重の支払を許可する。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Comment: 連続したハイフンだけの行はMarkdown記法では[見出しとして扱われてしまいます](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers)。別の書き方にするか、コードブロックを使った方がよいでしょう。